# Display shipping method amount including VAT on PDF Invoice

Tags: magento, invoice

When I generate a PDF invoice, the shipping Method block displays the shipping company and the amount (costs) of shipping.. This amount however is without VAT.

[See: Screenshot of the current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtRaI.png)

How can I change this?

I've set Display shipping amount to "Including Tax" in configuration -> TAX - > Orders, invoices,...settings

Note: In the magento backend the shipping costs are always displayed including VAT.

Should I change something in my configuration, or should I change the abstract.php to display the correct shipping costs including VAT?

Answer (score 1):

Take a local copy of `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php` and edit the function `insertOrder()` around line no 446 change `$totalShippingChargesText = "(" . Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Shipping Charges') . " ". $order->formatPriceTxt($order->getShippingAmount()) . ")";` to `$totalShippingChargesText = "(" . Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Shipping Charges') . " ". $order->formatPriceTxt($order->getShippingInclTax()) . ")";`

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is in a different fieldset.
Look at the System->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Calculation Settings
In that area there is a dropdown for shipping prices. Change that to include tax.[image]

Comment: Hi Russel, I checked this setting, but it was already set to "including tax".